# Is there any 'flavour' of ubuntu that comes with East Asian language support?

Tags: language-support, japanese, chinese, korean

Is there any 'flavour' of ubuntu that comes with East Asian language support? Or does anyone have a suggestion about what 'flavour' is more suitable for working with Chinese, Japanese and Korean? I still prefer to have the default system langauge English.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/791834/japanese-input-on-16-04-with-fcitx-and-mozc, and probably something similar for Korean as well. Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420774/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-kylin-and-ubuntu-with-default-language-chi

Comment: @muru: Objection to this being a duplicate. The OP seems to be asking about _which flavor is more suitable for the purpose_.

Answer (score 2):

All the flavors have support for CJK languages, even if I think that standard Ubuntu has the most user friendly interface to set it up.

Then there is Ubuntu Kylin which comes with Simplified Chinese by default, but since you want English as system language, that flavor is probably not the most suitable.